# Call Soap Webservice from Oracle pl/sql-getting error

Tags: oracle, web-services, plsql, soap

When I call SOAP Service I get "ORA-29266: end-of-body reached" error. I test my script with public test api" like [http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso"](http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso%22)

My script is like :

```
DECLARE
  req          UTL_HTTP.req;
  resp         UTL_HTTP.resp;
  url          VARCHAR2(200) := 'http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso';
  action       VARCHAR2(200) := 'http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso/NumberToWords';
  envelope     XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
                                  <soapenv:Header/>
                                  <soapenv:Body>
                                    <web:NumberToWords>
                                      <web:ubiNum>4</web:ubiNum>
                                    </web:NumberToWords>
                                  </soapenv:Body>
                                </soapenv:Envelope>');
  buffer       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(url, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(req, 'SOAPAction', action);
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(envelope.getClobVal()));
  UTL_HTTP.write_text(req, envelope.getClobVal());
  resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response(req);
  LOOP
    UTL_HTTP.read_line(resp, buffer);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(buffer);
    EXIT WHEN resp.status_code = 200; 
  END LOOP;
  UTL_HTTP.end_response(resp);  
END;
```

Normally I should get this response and extract the data from there:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <m:NumberToWordsResponse xmlns:m="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
         <m:NumberToWordsResult>forty seven thousand eight hundred and ninety nine</m:NumberToWordsResult>
      </m:NumberToWordsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But i  get "ORA-29266: end-of-body reached" error  and   get  DBMS Output  like this:

````
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso">here</a></body>```
````

Answer (score 0):

This end-point doesn't support http anymore, uses https.

tested with RapiAPI:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <m:NumberToWordsResponse xmlns:m="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
      <m:NumberToWordsResult>four </m:NumberToWordsResult>
    </m:NumberToWordsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```